# can we rename Linux driver name(driver.ko) and install?

Tags: driver, rename, linux-device-driver

Currently, there is a compiled kernel module file(driver.ko), and after we installed it, we can use "lsmod" command to view the driver, and the displayed name is "driver".

Now, we try to modify "driver.ko" to "test.ko", and then install it. we can install success, but the displayed name is "driver" when we use "lsmod" to view.

Is there any way to modify "driver.ko" to "test.ko", and make the displayed name to "test"? or is there any driver generate tools on Linux, which same as "windriver" on Windows(user only need input device id, vendor id, driver name and other paramters, the tool will generate a driver file).

thanks.

We try to rebuild source code to "test.ko", it can works normally. but we only want to provide "driver.ko" to user, and user can modify the driver name to others.

Comment: You need to recompile at least the piece that has name assignment. Yes, you may split code to several modules, one of which will be in the source code.